# How to import data from Google Sheets into Protege?

Tags: protege

I'm finding it shockingly difficult to find a straight answer to this online- I have information in a spreadsheet that I'm looking to import essentially as a series of triples. I'm wondering if there's a plugin or functionality that would allow me to import a csv and match column headers to existing classes, object properties, and data properties, for example:

| Individual | owl:Class | ont:isFullyEdible |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | ont:Fruit | "FALSE" |
| Potato | ont:Vegetable | "TRUE" |
| Avocado | ont:Fruit | "FALSE" |

The only things I'm seeing online are importing existing ontologies, or Protege documentation that hasn't been updated in over 15 years and is no longer applicable.

Comment: Ecport to Excel, then use the Cellfie plugin for Protege.